# shapely wkt.loads - skip bad geometries?

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, shapely

I'm trying to convert an excel file into a Geopandas dataframe. I'm trying to use shapely and wkt to do so.

After reading the file into pandas, I have a geometry column. I'm trying to do the following to convert the geometry column to an 'object' data type:

```
from shapely import wkt

my_df['geometry'] = my_df['geometry'].apply(wkt.loads)
```

and I receive the following error:

```
WKTReadingError: Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input.
```

To try and diagnose what the problem is, I also tried to convert this excel file to a geodataframe, using the following code:

```
import geopandas

my_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(my_df, geometry='geometry')
```

and I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Input must be valid geometry objects: MULTIPOLYGON (((1314112.145833299 1027703.927083313, 1314091.947916642 1027761.937499985, 1314232.583333299 1027811.447916642, 1314240.99999997 1027814.395833313, 1314246.739583299 1027794.468749985, 1314292.71874997 1027692.947916642, 1314282.18749997 1027689.010416642, 1314136.364583299 1027634.374999985, 1314112.145833299 1027703.927083313)))
```

It appears I only have one bad geometry? (Or it could just be the first bad geometry).

Can I just skip this bad one in the wkt.loads step?  I could not find documentation or other examples of how to do this.

Comment: Perhaps you can wrap `wkt.loads` in a new function that uses a `try/except` to catch the `WKTReadingError` and returns a `False` for the failed geometries. This way you could at least see which WKT strings are the bad ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I do this. Note that I remove the failed geometries using dropna:

```
from shapely import wkt
import pandas as pd

def wkt_loads(x):
    try:
        return wkt.loads(x)
    except Exception:
        return None

df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(wkt_geom=[
    'POINT (10 10)',
    'bad geometry',
    'POINT (20 20)',
]))

df['geometry'] = df.wkt_geom.apply(wkt_loads)
df = df.dropna(subset=['geometry'])
```